# CSS Nested scrollbars overlapping with dynamic content at 100% width

Tags: html, css

The code below shows two nested divs, each with automatic Y scrolling.

Is there a CSS solution to allow the user to see the inner scrollbar but keep the inner div at 100% width?

[image]

```css
div {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto
}
#outer { height: 400px; }
#inner { height: 200px; }
button { float: right; color: #F60}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('outerContent').innerHTML='smaller content does not need to scroll #inner should should still be 100% width of #outer'">TRY WITH SMALLER CONTENT</button>

<div id='outer'>
  <span id='outerContent'>Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which
  causes scroll Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which
  causes scroll</span>

  <div id='inner'>INNER DIV ALSO NEEDS TO SCROLL BUT I CANT SEE THE SCROLLBAR INNER DIV ALSO NEEDS TO SCROLL BUT I CANT SEE THE SCROLLBAR INNER DIV ALSO NEEDS TO SCROLL BUT I CANT SEE THE SCROLLBAR INNER DIV ALSO NEEDS TO SCROLL BUT I CANT SEE THE SCROLLBAR INNER DIV
    ALSO NEEDS TO SCROLL BUT I CANT SEE THE SCROLLBAR INNER DIV ALSO NEEDS TO SCROLL BUT I CANT SEE THE SCROLLBAR INNER DIV ALSO NEEDS TO SCROLL BUT I CANT SEE THE SCROLLBAR
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: <button onclick="document.getElementById('outerContent').innerHTML='smaller content does not need to scroll #inner should should still be 100% width of #outer';document.getElementById('inner').style.overflow = 'hidden'">TRY WITH SMALLER CONTENT</button>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's very well possible.

What you need is to apply `width:auto` and `display:block` to `#inner`. As these are applied by default in most (or all?) browsers, you should actually not need to set these. However, as you apply a fixed width in your CSS line 3 (`div { width: 200px }`) you remove the default behavior where `#inner` will adjust to the width of its parent.

---

You can solve this by either applying `width:200px` to `#outer` alone, not both divs:

```
/* The fixed width is removed from div... */
div {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto
}

/* ...and applied only to #outer */
#outer { height: 400px; width: 200px; }
#inner { height: 200px; }
```

See how this works in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnfc50r3/1/)

---

Or you can apply `width:200px` to both divs (as you are currently doing) and then revert this by applying `width:auto` to `#inner`.

```
/* Fixed width applied to both divs... */
div {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  height: 400px;
  width: 200px;
  overflow-y: auto
}

/* ...and the width is reverted to default on #inner */
#outer { height: 400px; }
#inner { height: 200px; width: auto; }
```

See the second snippet in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vnfc50r3/)

Answer (score 1):

Just make the `#inner` to be `width:auto`.

This way (*since it is a block element*) it will occupy as much as possible but the scrollbar will appear where it needs when required.

```css
div {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  width: 200px;
  height: 400px;
  overflow-y: auto
}
#outer { height: 400px; }
#inner { height: 200px; width:auto;}
button { float: right; color: #F60}
```

```html
<button onclick="document.getElementById('outerContent').innerHTML='smaller content does not need to scroll #inner should should still be 100% width of #outer'">TRY WITH SMALLER CONTENT</button>

<div id='outer'>
  <span id='outerContent'>Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which
  causes scroll Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which causes scroll Some long content which
  causes scroll</span>

  <div id='inner'>INNER DIV ALSO NEEDS TO SCROLL BUT I CANT SEE THE SCROLLBAR INNER DIV ALSO NEEDS TO SCROLL BUT I CANT SEE THE SCROLLBAR INNER DIV ALSO NEEDS TO SCROLL BUT I CANT SEE THE SCROLLBAR INNER DIV ALSO NEEDS TO SCROLL BUT I CANT SEE THE SCROLLBAR INNER DIV
    ALSO NEEDS TO SCROLL BUT I CANT SEE THE SCROLLBAR INNER DIV ALSO NEEDS TO SCROLL BUT I CANT SEE THE SCROLLBAR INNER DIV ALSO NEEDS TO SCROLL BUT I CANT SEE THE SCROLLBAR
  </div>
</div>
```